# Memory Leak on MapView with Overlays (Osmdroid)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, overlay, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have a problem with a memory leak in my app “Sensor Recording”. It has several activities, one of them a map activity (based on **osmdroid 6.1.8**), where I show a background **MAPNIK** with some **GroundOverlay**s containing weather maps.

[image]

When I switch between the activities - or when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape and back - the memory consumption is increasing each time, when the map is rebuilt. Sooner or later (depending upon the device memory) I will get an **OutOfMemoryError**.

For some more detailed info, here are extracts of the java source code, cleaned up of all the rubbish around it. The **map activity**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    .
    .
    .
    // basic map
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

    // overlays
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    WeatherOverlay weatherOverlay = new WeatherOverlay(this, mapView, wdStack);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(0, weatherOverlay);
    .
    .
    .
}  // onCreate
```

and the **class WeatherOverlay**:

```
public class WeatherOverlay extends Overlay implements Runnable
{
    private GroundOverlay[] groundOverlay;

    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

    private Context      context;
    private MapView      mapView;
    private WeatherStack wdStack;


    // constructor
    public WeatherOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView, WeatherStack wdStack)
    {
        super();

        this.context     = context;
        this.mapView     = mapView;
        this.wdStack     = wdStack;

        groundOverlay = new GroundOverlay[wdStack.getSize()];

        for (int index = 0; index < wdStack.getSize(); index++)
        {
            groundOverlay[index] = new GroundOverlay();
    
            groundOverlay[index].setPosition(
                    wdStack.getEntry(index).northWest,
                    wdStack.getEntry(index).southEast);
    
            mapView.getOverlays().add(0, groundOverlay[index]);
        }

        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    }  // constructor


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        if (shadow) return;

        new Thread(this).start();

    }  // draw


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        final boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!isConnected)
        {
            return;
        }


        // get URL
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpsURLConnection connection;
        String UrlString = "";


        // try to get input stream
        try
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < wdStack.getSize(); index++)
            {
                if ((wdStack.getEntry(index).URL != null) &&
                        (wdStack.getEntry(index).onOff))
                {
                    UrlString = wdStack.getEntry(index).URL;     // e.g. "https://en.sat24.com/image?type=km&region=de" for "Germany"

                    URL url = new URL(UrlString);
                    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();   // possible OutOfMemoryError

                    // read the image
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    inputStream.close();
                    inputStream = null;

                    // and put it into ground overlay
                    if ((bitmap != null) && (groundOverlay[index] != null))
                    {
                        groundOverlay[index].setImage(bitmap);
                        wdStack.getEntry(index).downloaded = true;
                    }

                    // show on the map
                    mapView.postInvalidateDelayed(100);
                }  // if onOff
            }  // for index
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
        }

    }  // run

}  // class
```

Any ideas, how I can track down and fix that memory leak?

Comment: I think you should cancel the runnable and release resources (specifically the thread) in the overlay's destroy.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but how to do it? Can you provide a code snippet? All my tests with myThread.stop() and myThread.destroy() ended up with a crash of the app.

Answer (score 0):

`onDraw(...)` is an important method and must be efficient. For example, we shouldn't define any new variable. Because it invokes every time that your view/overlay has any change to draw the latest info on screen.

So you should use the contractor to initialize variables i.e your Thread.

Then you should override [onDetach(MapView)](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Overlay.html#onDetach-org.osmdroid.views.MapView-) in your Overlay class. because based on OsmDroid document you should release all resources in this method. (in your case stop and kill thread and and null other huge resources)

> public void onDetach(MapView mapView)
>
> Override to perform clean up of resources before shutdown. By default
> does nothing.

[source](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Overlay.html#onDetach-org.osmdroid.views.MapView-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to avoid memory leaks was the following code in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop ()
{
    mapView.onDetach(); 

    super.onStop();
}  // onStop
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem here is that  `MapView::onDetach()` nulls out a bunch of internal references (e.g. in `MapViewRepository`). It's effecitlvey a final action that destroys the mapView. So unless you explicitly re-create it `onStart()`, you'll get some NPE explosions.